# MS Access add a missing date between range

Tags: ms-access

I have a Lease Table with Start and End Dates. I need to add the records to fill the missing date range. To calculate the Vacancy of the property. I am working in Access.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop the table - as in this example inserting missing hours:

```
Public Function FillWindLog()

  Dim dbs     As DAO.Database
  Dim rst     As DAO.Recordset

  Dim datMin  As Date
  Dim datMax  As Date
  Dim datLog  As Date
  Dim datNew  As Date
  Dim datOld  As Date

  Set dbs = CurrentDb
  Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("Select * From tblWindLog Order By DateLog")
  With rst
    ' Find first and last logging date.
    .MoveLast
    datMax = !DateLog.value
    .MoveFirst
    datMin = !DateLog.value
    ' Set initial low value of empty interval.
    datOld = datMin
    ' Set initial high value of current empty interval.
    datLog = datMin
    .MoveNext
    ' Locate empty intervals.
    ' Stop when reaching the last of the old records.
    While .EOF = False And datLog < datMax
      ' Set high value of a possible empty interval.
      datLog = !DateLog.value
      ' Increment low value of possible empty interval by one hour.
      datNew = DateAdd("h", 1, datOld)
      ' Fill empty intervals with hourly recordings of Null values.
      Do While DateDiff("h", datNew, datLog) >= 1 And datNew < datMax
        .AddNew
          !DateLog.value = datNew
        .Update
        datNew = DateAdd("h", 1, datNew)
      Loop
      ' Set low value of the next possible empty interval.
      datOld = datLog
      .MoveNext
    Wend
    .Close
  End With

  Set rst = Nothing
  Set dbs = Nothing

End Function
```

You should be able to modify it to insert full dates instead of hours.